# Randoop on windowns -No class with the name "ParserConfigurationSettings" found on the classpath

Tags: java, windows, command-line, classpath, randoop

Hello I'm getting the following erro after put the following command in the MS-DOS:

```
    C:\Users\Aline\Desktop\ClassesdoEstudodeCaso\ProjetosSelecionados\xerces-2.10.0\bin\org\apache\xerces\util>java -ea -classpath randoop.jar randoop.main.Main gentests --testclass=ParserConfigurationSettings --timelimit=60

policy = sun.security.provider.PolicyFile@10f87f48
    Error: No class with name "ParserConfigurationSettings" found on the classpath
           This is most likely a problem with the classpath. It may be wrong, or
           it is formatted incorrectly on the command line. The other possibility
           is that the wrong class name is given.
    Exiting Randoop.
```

And the "C:\Users\Aline\Desktop\ClassesdoEstudodeCaso\ProjetosSelecionados\xerces-2.10.0\bin\org\apache\xerces\util" already is in the classpath

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the Randoop error message that you quoted, you have specified the classpath incorrectly.

Your command line contains `-classpath randoop.jar`.  This classpath does not contain the class `ParserConfigurationSettings`.

As shown in the [Running Randoop](https://randoop.github.io/randoop/manual/index.html#running_randoop) section of the [Randoop Manual](https://randoop.github.io/randoop/manual/index.html), the classpath needs to contain both Randoop and the code being tested.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the command

```
java -ea -classpath randoop.jar;C:\Users\Aline\Desktop\ClassesdoEstudodeCaso\ProjetosSelecionados\xerces-2.10.0\bin\org\apache\xerces\util\ randoop.main.Main gentests --testclass=ParserConfigurationSettings --timelimit=10
```

But it didn't work, trying some other commands I found this one that worked:

```
java -ea -classpath randoop.jar;C:\Users\Aline\Desktop\ClassesdoEstudodeCaso\ProjetosSelecionados\xerces-2.10.0\bin\ randoop.main.Main gentests --testclass=org.apache.xerces.util.ParserConfigurationSettings --timelimit=60
```

Comment: The classpath always contains the directory where you would expect to see the first part of the package name (e.g., `org`) as a subdirectory, and Randoop expects the class name to be fully qualified by the package name. So, the first is defective in both ways.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this follow below steps:-

Applicable for linux/unix and mac-os

you can map it to windows accordingly

1. Check `JAVA_HOME` is correctly specified or not, if not do export `JAVA_HOME=<java home dir>`
   execute  `echo $JAVA_HOME`
   and add variable in system `PATH`

   export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
2. Click on [link](https://randoop.github.io/randoop/manual/) . to download Randoop, extract on your system.
3. Setup `RANDOOP_PATH` and `RANDOOP_JAR` as environment variable and add in system `PATH`.

   export RANDOOP_PATH=
   export RANDOOP_JAR=$RANDOOP_PATH/randoop-all-.jar
   export PATH=$RANDOOP_PATH:$RANDOOP_JAR:$PATH
4. goto  and create `/bin/src/main/java` and `/bin/src/test/java` folders
5. Open Terminal and execute command `java -ea -classpath $RANDOOP_JAR randoop.main.Main help`

expected output

> Randoop for Java version .
>
> Randoop  is a command-line tool that creates unit tests for Java. It
>   accepts one of the commands listed below. For the user manual, please
>   visit https://randoop.github.io/randoop/manual/index.html
>
> Type `help' followed by a command name to see documentation.
>
> Commands:
>
> gentests -- Generates unit tests for a set of classes.
>
> help -- Displays a help message for a given command.
>
> **Randoop setup is completed and ready to use.**

6. If you want to execute Randoop on class XYZ to generate test case follow below steps

6.1 `XYZ.class` is class file having package name as `com.demo` 
then create the folder `/com/demo` under  `$RANDOOP_HOME/bin/src/main/java/` i.e. `$RANDOOP_HOME/bin/src/main/java/com/demo/` and place `XYZ.class` file here.

6.2 Now execute below command from terminal

```
java  -ea -classpath $RANDOOP_PATH/bin/src/main/java:$RANDOOP_JAR:$JAVA_HOME/bin randoop.main.Main gentests --testclass=com.demo.XYZ --timelimit=60  --outputlimit=500 --inputlimit=500 --testsperfile=500 --error-test-basename=XYZError --regression-test-basename=XYZRegression --junit-package-name=com.demo --junit-output-dir=$RANDOOP_PATH/bin/src/test/java
```

6.3 Once 6.2 is completed goto `$RANDOOP_PATH/bin/src/test/java` and verify the files are created or not!!!

6.4 now you can execute this Tests with `Junit.jar`.

Comment: Hi! Looks like your entire post is formatted as code, please try to format using the following guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting to make it more readable.